# Entity Framework Model First DateTime default value

Tags: entity-framework-6, ef-model-first

I'm trying to give some DateTime fields default values from the model browser.

Whatever I type into the Default Value field, I get an error telling me `The value must be in the form 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fffZ'`.  I am assuming that format string uses the scheme documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

The value I punched in is `2014-05-23 00:00:00.0000`, which I believe is of that form.  I'm not sure whether `0` is a valid value for the `Z` component, but I don't know what the right value would be.

What could be wrong with the string I gave?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  The Z component was indeed the issue.  I just needed to use `2014-05-23 00:00:00.000Z` instead.